# onClick a font awesome icon, run PHP without Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay right, Ajax. But is there any other solution besides ajax. You cannot really make a font-awesome icon a button or can you? If you have no clue what I am talking about when I mean a font-awesome icon this is what I mean:

```
<i id="like1" onClick="like(this);" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">5</i>&nbsp;
```

So back on topic. I want to make it as soon as you click on this icon it runs a php script which adds a +1 to a text file, but how would you run that without using ajax and without refreshing the page. The site I am working on is a random youtube video site where people will be able to rate videos. I want to save when someone clicks the thumbs up button but I cannot refresh the page or else it goes to another random video. Now you see my issue. However if it is not possible to do without ajax then please explain the ajax solution, I do not have enough experience with ajax to do it on my own. Heres some code that I've already done.

JS:

```
<script>
function like(obj) {
    if (obj.style.color === "green") {
        // set obj color to something other than green
        obj.style.color = "white";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, decrement by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) - 1;
    }
    else {
        // we are incrementing, so check the dislike and decrement if necessary
        var dislike = document.getElementById("dislike1");
        if (dislike.style.color === 'red') {
            dislike.style.color = 'white';
            dislike.innerText = parseInt(dislike.innerText) - 1;
        }
        // set the colour of the object that was clicked
        obj.style.color = "green";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, and increment by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) + 1;
    }
}
</script>
<script>
function dislike(obj) {
    if (obj.style.color === "red") {
        // set obj color to something other than green
        obj.style.color = "white";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, decrement by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) - 1;
    }
    else {
        // we are incrementing, so check the dislike and decrement if necessary
        var like = document.getElementById("like1");
        if (like.style.color === 'green') {
            like.style.color = 'white';
            like.innerText = parseInt(like.innerText) - 1;
        }
        // set the colour of the object that was clicked
        obj.style.color = "red";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, and increment by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) + 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

Dislike & like buttons:

```
  <strong><i id="like1" onClick="like(this);" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">5</i>&nbsp;
    <i id="dislike1" onClick="dislike(this);" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">1</i>&nbsp;<br/></strong>
```

EDIT:
Is this correct?

```
<script>
function like(obj) {
var jqxhr = $.ajax(
  type: "POST",
  url: "liketest.php",   //Name of your current file name
  data: shareline                //Here pass some parameters. Detect it in your php file before proceeding furthur. These parameters are available in post global variable when you send an ajax call.

) 
      .done(function(msg ) {
      echo "Ajax seems fine";
  })
  .fail(function() {
   echo "Failed";
  })

  });
    if (obj.style.color === "green") {
        // set obj color to something other than green
        obj.style.color = "white";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, decrement by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) - 1;
    }
    else {
        // we are incrementing, so check the dislike and decrement if necessary
        var dislike = document.getElementById("dislike1");
        if (dislike.style.color === 'red') {
            dislike.style.color = 'white';
            dislike.innerText = parseInt(dislike.innerText) - 1;
        }
        // set the colour of the object that was clicked
        obj.style.color = "green";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, and increment by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) + 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you can make an icon clickable.

Comment: How so? I've attempted to use <form> But unfortunately it just makes another button next to the icon? Can you provide a more detailed explanation of this? And it is possible to make it do something without having to refresh the page?

Comment: Also if your talking about just using a js function. That is correct. But using a <form> function not really. What i'm trying to do is somehow make it do something within PHP. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not execute any php script on client computer. PHP is a server side scripting language and its only executable on server side. You have to use ajax function if you don't want to refresh the page.

Use jQuery ajax function to save values in your text file.

You can get more help about ajax function on following website. Following is the syntax for jquery.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(
  type: "POST",
  url: "pageFileName.php",   //Name of your current file name
  data: data                //Here pass some parameters. Detect it in your php file before proceeding furthur. These parameters are available in post global variable when you send an ajax call.

) 
      .done(function(msg ) {
        // Here you will put the code which will execute after successful ajax call. msg variable contain data which is received from your php script file. 
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // Code if ajax call fail
  })

  });
```

Comment: Okay. I understand you don't want to spoon feed me. But this is not a solution. I've already attempted doing that. Don't you think it would be logical for me to go to try ajax before going here? I've already tried doing that type of solution but unfortunately it does not work with my code. Thats the reason I posted it.

Comment: You have only posted java script code here.I can not help you only with this code. can you provide the complete code of the page? So I can see why ajax is not working in your website. There should be some problem into your code that why ajax is not working.

Comment: May be you are not using correct syntax for your ajax call. I am adding how to use ajax call in jquery in my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks for helping. This is the full code basically through. I posted the JS and thats what matters. However i don't want php from another file. I have php on the same page. How would I execute that?

Comment: I given ajax sytax in answer. Replace "phpSCriptFile.php" with the file name of your page. This will send ajax call to same page. But it will also return the content of your current page. So append some parameters and check these parameters with php. If these parameters found than it will return with out further processing. I have updated syntax of the ajax call in answer.

Comment: Okay I changed it. Scroll up and see where it says Is this correct? When I do it like that it does not want to work?

Comment: In data you sent a jason object like data : { kye1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' }. You access this data from super global post array by giving the key. In your case you only need to check if this key is exist in post array or not. If this key found in post array then it is an ajax call. In case ajax what so ever you echo in php return back in the msg variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself (except in nodejs with Socket.io) but if you don't want to use an ajax call, for some reason, you could maybe try *WebSockets*.

Short presentation here: [MDN WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)